# Simulate Button Click Event in Console

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

We are trying to view all the listings present at
https://www.pimco.com/en-us/insights

But the webpage has button that restricts viewing all the listings at once.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByZFU.png)

In JavaScript, Is it possible to click on the button recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `querySelector()` function can be used to find the button element on the page.

The `click()` function on button element can be called to trigger "simulate" a button click.

As it takes some time we should wait before trying to press the button again.

This part `setTimeout(loadMore, 5000);` controls how long to wait the code in this cause 5000ms or 5 seconds, before it call loadMore again.

```js
function loadMore() {
 const button = document.querySelector('.loadMoreText')
 if (button) {
   button.click();
   console.log('Button Clicked');
 }
 else {
   console.log('No button');
 }
  console.log('Waiting for 5 seconds');
  setTimeout(loadMore, 5000);
}
loadMore()
```

Comment: as perfect as nature